# Is there a way in Angular to transform an array of strings into a modified array of strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## problem

I want to take an array of strings: `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` and transform them into a modified array `["hello foo apple", "hello bar apple", "hello baz apple"]` inside an angular template.

#### supplemental information

Taking this array I already have a utility function in a controller that will let me `sentence-ify` the array to be `"hello foo apple, hello bar apple, and hello baz apple"`.  If the array were of different lengths, it would account for the lengths and show them differently, for example `[1,2]` becomes `"1 and 2"`, or `[1]` becomes`"1"`, or '[1,2,3,4,5]' becomes `"1, 2, 3, 4, and 5"`.

```html
<div ng-if="array_foo">
    {{array_foo sentence-ify}}
</div>
```

The above code would give me:

```
<div>hello foo apple, hello bar apple, and hello baz apple</div>
```

I know that you can use `ng-repeat` but as far as i know it doesn't actually return an array, rather it returns an html of the repeated items.

I simply need to transform the array into a modified array(map) but can't find the documentation after searching around.  Is there a way I can do this?  I feel like its a very simple operation so I must be missing something when I look for an answer.

Comment: which array are you trying to transform and into what exactly, can you elaborate more ?

Comment: If you want to modify the original array then use Array.Prototype.ForEach(). If you want to create new array and leave original array as Unchanged then use Array.Prototype.Map()

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like a filter

```
<div ng-if="array_foo">
    {{array_foo | myFormat}}
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x) {
        if(!angular.isArray(x))return x;
        return x.map(function (item, index, arr) {
          if(index+1 === arr.length) return " and hello " + item + " apple";
          return "hello " + item + " apple";
        }).join(',');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do some thing like this :

```js
var originalArray = ["foo", "bar"];

originalArray = originalArray.map(function (item) {
  return "Hello " + item + " apple";
});

console.log(originalArray)
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - `array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)